# How to handle AuthGuard in Angular when using public routes

Tags: angular, authentication

My current AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    if (this.authService.userStatus$.getValue()) {
      return true;
    }

    return this.authService.authenticateUser().pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of(null);
      }),
      map((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/commands']);
        return false;
      })
    );
  }
```

The idea is that when I place this AuthGuard on a protected route, it will first check if my AuthService already contains a logged in user, and if not, it will try to fetch the authentication status. This handles the case where if I refresh the page and lose the user status, it will automatically fetch it again on my protected route.

The problem is that I have a navbar that displays `Login`/`Log Out` depending on the user's logged in status. This navbar is present in both public and private routes. My public routes do not use my AuthGuard, so my navbar can never know if a user is logged in on those public routes (since I only check for a user's auth status in my AuthGuard). I thought maybe it would be a good idea to check for a user's auth status in my navbar component (outside the AuthGuard)

The issue with that is that is I end up making duplicate requests on my private routes that contain the navbar. Because the AuthGuard is fetching a user's status, and the Navbar is also fetching the user status. I also found that my AuthGuard gets triggered before any service calls, so only authenticating outside the guard would not work as far as I understand.

I want to be able to have users use some of these routes regardless of login status, while also populating my navbar correctly without duplicating requests.

Currently, my way around this is to assign my AuthGuard to all routes (public or private), and hard code the public ones to return true so that a user can still navigate to that route.

Something like this:

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    if (this.authService.userStatus$.getValue()) {
      return true;
    }

    return this.authService.authenticateUser().pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of(null);
      }),
      map((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return true;
        }

        // Allow the user to access public route after authenticating for navbar
        if (this.acceptableRoutes.includes(route.routeConfig.path)) {
          return true;
        }
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      })
    );
  }
```

But adding an AuthGuard to all my routes just so I can fetch the Auth status for my navbar seems like a roundabout way of achieving what I want. The navbar is not always present on my pages, and so it would be nice to *not* have to authenticate on load everywhere.

Comment: do you have a simple stackblitz about this? I'm trying to wrap my head around the "request" you mentioned but couldn't really understand. In my mind, it just one request all along.